# Update a "updated_at" column at a specific table on each post method I make

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make "Last update time" for a project, and  have created a table and I will update "updated_at" every time I make a post method from my project, is there anyway to create it without having to add it in every controller that I  make update and store.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Model Observer, 2. Model event. The latter might more convenient combined with usage of PHP trait in my point of view.

Comment: use Helper.php and send parameters to the method. However, it will also call where you needed.

Comment: You can create a middleware and in the `handle` update the updated_at then apply ths middleware to the web group routes and you can test if it is a post request with `$request->isMethod('post')` [more about middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware) ;)

Comment: No, middleware is not designed for handling post logic thingy. As the name call, `updated_at` should be updated when the model is updated. By using, middleware means you have to handle all the stuffs mostly controller handling on, to the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Just include this in your migration  `$table->timestamps();`, in order to add 
created_at and updated_at,

*Reference to create a model* https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent

Then create a model for the table you need, and every time you `->update()` any record the update_at timestamp will be changed automatically.